# Why does my set of pair<int,int> contains duplicates?

Tags: duplicates, integer, set

I am puzzled with a set of pair<int,int> that contains inconsistent duplicates. The first elements of the set are inserted correctly then, after inserting a kth pair, all pairs in the set are replaced with duplicate pairs of new int values.

The set is filled within a loop as follows

```html
//the coordinates are stored in vector of pair<double,double> with dimension N :
vector<pair<double,double> > coordPairs(N);  

//populate "coordPairs" 

... 


std::set <std::pair<int,int> > occupiedCellList;

for(int i=0; i<coordPairs.size(); i++)
{   
    double x, y;
    x = coordPairs[i].first;
    y = coordPairs[i].second;

    int row = (y - ymin) / cellSizeInMeters;
    int col = (x - xmin) / cellSizeInMeters;
  
    occupiedCellList.insert(make_pair(row,col));              
}
```

Even when I use floor or trunc in the expressions of row and col the set still contains duplicates. How can this behaviour be explained ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

What appeared to be duplicates was not. The "error" came from the debugger in QT creator that wrongly displays set elements.

When displaying with std::cout element of the set using set iterator, all elements were OK.

```
set<pair<int,int>> s;
...
//populate elements of s
...    
set<pair<int,int>>::iterator it = s.begin();
while(it!=s.end())
{
    cout<< it->first << ", " << it->second << endl;
    it++;
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: The origin of the problem QT-creator's debugger UI. It is not able to correctly display values of the set of pairs. I finally checked the actual values stored in my set and found them correct.